# How can I fix this error : 'Cannot invoke loadPixels() on the array type PImage[]'?

Tags: arrays, processing, pixel

I'm kind of a beginner with Processing and I've been having difficulty with my pixel array. I have 10 images numbered from 0-9 that are being shown one after another... What I am trying to do on top of that is take each image and change its brightness level, turning it either white or black.

I've already tried to just change the brightness using one image, so not an array of images which works perfectly! But when joining those two together it doesn't work for me.

```java
int maxImages = 10;  // The number of frames in the animation
int imageIndex = 00; //initial image to be displayed first
PImage[] picture = new PImage[maxImages]; //the image array

void setup() {
  size(500, 500); //size of sketch
  frameRate(1); //frames processed per second

  //loading images with numbered files into the array
  for (int i = 0; i< picture.length; i++) {
    picture[i] = loadImage("spast_" + i + ".jpg");
  }
} 

void draw() { 

  image(picture[imageIndex], 0, 0); //dispaying one image
  loadPixels(); //accessing pixels

  picture.loadPixels();  //accessing the image pixels too
 //THIS is where it stops me and gives me 'Cannot invoke loadPixels() on the array type PImage[]'

  for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) { //loops through every single x value
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) { //loops through every single y value
      int loc = x + y*width; // declare integer loc

      float b = brightness(picture.pixels[loc]); //give me the brightness of pixels
      if (b < 150) { //if the pixel is lower than 150
        pixels[loc] = color(0); //then make those pixels black
      } else { //otherwise
        pixels[loc] = color(255); //make pixels white
      }
    }
  }
  imageIndex = (imageIndex + 1) % picture.length; //increment image index by one each cycle
  updatePixels(); //when finished with the pixel array update the pixels
}
```

I'm expecting as each image is displayed it brightness value is changed and then it goes on to image 2 and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Your `picture` variable is an **array** of `PImage` instances. You can't call `loadPixels()` on the array itself. You have to get a `PImage` at a specific index of the array, and then call the `loadPixels()` function on that instance.

Here's an example:

```
picture[0].loadPixels();
```

This line of code gets the `PImage` at index 0 and calls the `loadPixels()` function on it.

Note that you're already doing something pretty similar with this line:

```
image(picture[imageIndex], 0, 0);
```

Shameless self-promotion: [here](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/arrays) is a tutorial on arrays in Processing.

Answer (score 0):

This is the updated and working code:

```
int maxImages = 10;  // The number of frames in the animation
int imageIndex = 0; //initial image to be displayed first
PImage[] picture = new PImage[maxImages]; //the image array

void setup() {
  size(500, 500); //size of sketch
  frameRate(1); //frames processed per second

  //loading images with numbered files into the array
  for (int i = 0; i< picture.length; i++) {
    picture[i] = loadImage("spast_" + i + ".jpg"); 
  }
} 

void draw() { 

  loadPixels(); //accessing pixels
  image(picture[imageIndex], 0, 0); //dispaying one image
  imageIndex = (imageIndex + 1) % picture.length; //increment image index by one each cycle

  picture[imageIndex].loadPixels();  //accessing the image pixels in the array
  for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) { //loops through every single x value
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) { //loops through every single y value
      int loc = x + y*width; // declare integer loc

      float b = brightness(picture[imageIndex].pixels[loc]); //give me the brightness of pixels
      if (b < 150) { //if the pixel is lower than 150
        pixels[loc] = color(0); //then make those pixels black
      } else { //otherwise
        pixels[loc] = color(255); //make pixels white
      }
    }
  }
  updatePixels(); //when finished with the pixel array update the pixels
}
```

Comment: great you got it goin'. quickly scanning the code it looks you're coding threshold filter. it's worth knowing you can also play with [`filter(THRESHOLD,0.58)`](https://processing.org/reference/filter_.html) for example.